# Magento hasoption not getting on list page when flat data enabled

Tags: magento, product

I am not able to fetch the hasoption value of a product in product collection in magento list page.

I tried adding this xml tag in my custom module

```
<config>
    <frontend>
         <product>
              <collection>
                   <attributes>
                      <MPN />
                      <JAN />
                      <UPC />
                   </attributes>
              </collection>
          </product>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

above code is wokring for product attributes, it is not working for hasoption value of product while flat data is turned on.

Any idea how to include hasoptions in magento flat data collection in list page.

Comment: Any answers  are appreciated

Comment: I got the solution, not need to add any xml tags. Just update the  database to include "has options" in product listing page.

Comment: `update catalog_eav_attribute set used_in_product_listing = 1 where attribute_id = 98;`   98 is the attribute id of hasoption product attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really have to add any XML for this.

Try setting ***`used_in_product_listing`*** field to `1` in **`catalog_eav_attribute`** table for the respective `attribute_id`.